# Django-piston and UserProfile

Tags: django, django-models, django-piston

I'm using Django-piston and I'd like to get user objects that include user profile data.

I'm trying :

```
class UserHandler(BaseHandler):
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'favorite_color')

...
```

favorite_color is defined in UserProfile

The result is only printing id and username and nothing for favorite color.

Comment: Are you sure favorite color value isn't empty? Just a guess - if favorite_color is defined in UserProfile (not on User model) you can't access it directly through User model.

Answer (score 0):

If your UserProfile is linked to the User via a OneToOneField, you should be able to do it by walking the relation, using the nested-tuple syntax. (The following is untested)

```
class UserHandler(BaseHandler):
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'username', ('userprofile', ('favorite_color',))

...
```

See [the docs](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation#!fieldsexclude) here

Answer (score 0):

check if you already use model=User in other handler

and look at this
https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/FAQ